# Making different fetchbasequery based on endpoint in RTK query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery(
{
  baseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL,
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token =
      getState().auth.accessToken ||
      JSON.parse(getAuthFromLocal())?.accessToken ||
      "";
    token && headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    return headers;
  },
});

const baseQueryWithReAuth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
  if (result?.error?.status === 403) {
    // get the new access token using refresh token
    const { refreshToken, ...rest } = JSON.parse(getAuthFromLocal());

    const newAccessToken = await baseQuery(
      "/refreshToken",
      api,
      extraOptions
    );
    // just storing the access token
    if (newAccessToken?.error?.status) {
      console.log("the fetch is false and has failed =====>", newAccessToken);
    } else {
      saveAuthToLocal({
        ...rest,
        refreshToken,
        accessToken: newAccessToken,
      });
    }
    // if refresh is not available or not able to get the new accessToken, that means the refreshToken must be expired
    if (newAccessToken) {
      // make the original request
      result = await baseQuery(agrs, api, extraOptions);
    } else {
      /*logout and remove the store*/
    }
  } else {
    console.log("the execution of the else part from api slice");
  }
  return result;
};

const ApiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReAuth,
  tagTypes: [
    ...all tags
  ],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});

export default ApiSlice;
```

---

As I am not using the cookies ,so I required to set the header with refreshToken explicitly when the accesstoken is expired which will have the error status code as 403. So to refetch the access token using endpoint /refreshToken which will have the refresh token in its header in authorisation bearer instead of access token, So how to set that while calling  `baseQuery("/refreshToken",api,extraOptions );` and avoid the header that is set by prepareHeaders.

Answer (score 1):

To set a custom header for your `baseQuery("/refreshToken", api, extraOptions)` call, you'll need to modify the headers that are passed.

Since `prepareHeaders` is always executed when `baseQuery` is called, find a way to bypass it or modify its behavior for this specific request.

One way is to add an additional parameter in `extraOptions` that indicates whether or not to set the authorization header with the access token. Then check for this parameter in `prepareHeaders` and modify the headers accordingly.

1. Add an `ignoreAccessToken` flag to `extraOptions` when calling `baseQuery` for the refresh token:

```js
const newAccessToken = await baseQuery(
  "/refreshToken",
  api,
  { ignoreAccessToken: true }
);
```

2. Modify the `prepareHeaders` function to check for this flag:

```js
prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState, extraOptions }) => {
  if (!extraOptions?.ignoreAccessToken) {
    const token =
      getState().auth.accessToken ||
      JSON.parse(getAuthFromLocal())?.accessToken ||
      "";
    token && headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
  } else {
    const refreshToken =
      JSON.parse(getAuthFromLocal())?.refreshToken || "";
    refreshToken && headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${refreshToken}`);
  }
  return headers;
},
```

Now when you set the `ignoreAccessToken` flag in `extraOptions`, the `prepareHeaders` function will use the refresh token for authorization instead of the access token.